# Specify dev_appserver.py arguments in PyCharm

Tags: google-app-engine, command-line-arguments, pycharm

I need to override the Automatic ID Allocation Policy for my Google AppEngine app by running the following:

```
dev_appserver.py --auto_id_policy=sequential
```

How do I specify App Engine arguments from the PyCharm IDE, or which file should I edit?

Answer (score 4):

You need to go to the run/debug configurations and add your options to the "additional options" box. Then those additional options will be used when the devserver is executed.

A quick way to get to this is to click the button next to the "run" button on the menu bar - that button should also display the name of your application. Click on it then click "edit configurations" and you should see the screen below.

[image]

Here the -c option (IIRC) clears the datastore each time the devserver is run.